# Generate random numbers without using the last n values in Python

Tags: python, random

I have a Python function that generates a random number between 0 and 100:

```
def get_next_number():
    value = randint(0,100)
```

Every time I call this function, I need it to return a random number but that number cannot be one of the last n random numbers it returned (lets say 5 for this example).

Here are some examples:

55, 1, 67, 12, 88, 91, 100, 54 (This is fine as there are no duplicates in the last 5 numbers returned)

77, 42, 2, 3, 88, 2... (When the function gets a random number of 2, I need it to try again since 2 was already returned 3 numbers prior)

89, 23, 29, 81, 99, 100, 6, 8, 23... (This one is fine because 23 occurred more than 5 times before)

Is there something built into the random function to accomplish this?

Comment: Save the last five numbers and tell the program to get a new random number if a match occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it *the other way round*.

Instead of generating a random number **and then** checking if it is already generated before, you can **generate the set of non-duplicate numbers first** to be picked up one by one - thus removing the possibility of generating duplicate number at all.

And you also need to track the last 5 items generated to exclude them from the picked items.

Something like this will do:

```
s = set(range(0, 100))
last5 = []
def get_next_number():
    reduced_list = list(s - set(last5))
    i = randint(0, len(reduced_list) - 1)
    last5.append(reduced_list[i])
    if len(last5) > 5:
        last5.pop(0)
    return reduced_list[i]
```

To test:

```
result = []
for i in range(0, 5000):
    result.append(get_next_number())
print(result)
```

---

**Step-by-step explanations:**

1. Generate the set of numbers to be picked up (say, 0 to 99) and generate an empty list to store the last 5 picked numbers:

   ```
   s = set(range(0, 100))
   last5 = []
   ```
2. In the method, exclude the last 5 picked numbers from the possibility from being picked:

   ```
   reduced_list = list(s - set(last5))
   ```
3. Pick random number from the `reduced_list`, all numbers left in the `reduced_list` is valid for picking. Append the number to the `last5` list

   ```
   i = randint(0, len(reduced_list) - 1) #get any valid index. -1 is needed because randint upperbound is inclusive
   last5.append(reduced_list[i]) #the number is as what it pointed by the index: reduced_list[i], append that number to the last 5 list
   ```
4. Check if the `last5` list already have members > 5. If it does, you need to remove its **first** member:

   ```
   if len(last5) > 5:
       last5.pop(0)
   ```
5. return you selected member:

   ```
   return reduced_list[i]
   ```

Comment: Not sure if this will work. When I go to generate the 12th number, it's possible it could have been one of the last 5 numbers used.

Comment: @user1624184 ok, my answer is updated. Kindly check again

Comment: Thanks for this - makes sense but I keep getting this error: last5.append(reduced_s[i]) IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @user1624184 sorry, forgot to put `-1` there... updated. please try again

Comment: @user1624184 `i = randint(0, len(reduced_list) - 1) #get any valid index. -1 is needed because randint upperbound is inclusive`

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this, you can use a iterator. Below is the sample code for that:

```
import random

class UniqueRandom(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.unused_nums = range(num)
        self.num = num

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.num:
            random_num = random.randrange(self.num)
            unique_num = self.unused_nums[random_num]
            self.unused_nums[random_num], self.unused_nums[self.num-1] = self.unused_nums[self.num-1], self.unused_nums[random_num]
            self.num -= 1
            return unique_num
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

For example to generate the random numbers between 0 to 100:

```
random_num = UniqueRandom(100)
print next(random_num)  # 54
print next(random_num)  # 33
```

To flush the values, create new iterator object:

```
random_num = UniqueRandom(100)
print next(random_num)  # 92
print next(random_num)  # 33 (repeated)
```

You may also use it within a list as:

```
>>> for i in UniqueRandom(5):
...     print i
... 
2
1
0
3
4
```

Comment: I don't need a unique random number every time.  After calling the function 5 times, I want the random numbers to be available again.

Comment: Use above logic within an iterator and call new iterator object when you want to flush the values

Comment: Added the iterator function. Verify it, it is working. Earlier it had some issue. Just updated the code

Answer (score 0):

How many random numbers do you need?

Use Python's builtin `random.sample` method. It lists **unique** elements chosen from the population sequence or set and is used for random sampling without replacement.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(range(1, 100), 3)
[56, 43, 74]
```

Create a large list of random integers. Then, `pop()` when required.

```
>>> rands = random.sample(range(1, 100), 20)
>>> rands
[63, 23, 68, 72, 18, 83, 56, 34, 19, 7, 51, 5, 89, 47, 26, 49, 2, 1, 93, 84]
>>> rands.pop()
84
>>> rands.pop()
93
```